# How to apply style to the certain item in .Net Maui?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xaml, maui

## Problem:

Need to apply style not for all flyout menus, only for a certain flyout.Please help me
Need to apply style not for all flyout menus, only for a certain flyout.Please help me
*

## Screenshots:

[image]

Need to apply styles for the first one, not for all of them

## Code:

```
<Shell
    
    x:Class="RakeshProj.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RakeshProj"
    FlyoutBackgroundColor="Gray">
    <!--<Shell.FlyoutHeader>
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="dotnet_bot.png"
          HeightRequest="142"
          VerticalOptions="Center"
          WidthRequest="230"
          HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </Shell.FlyoutHeader>-->
    <Shell.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label"
       Class="FlyoutItemLabelStyle">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" 
            Value="White" />
        </Style>
    </Shell.Resources>
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems"  >

        <ShellContent Title="Settings"
                      Icon="gear_solid.svg"
                      x:Name="ShellContent1_1"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" 
                      />

        <ShellContent Title="Remove Ads"
                      Icon="unlock_solid.svg"
                      x:Name="ShellContent2_1"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Usage tips"
                      Icon="circle_question_solid.svg"
                      x:Name="ShellContent3_1"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>..................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snice `ShellContent` does not provide the textcolor property , we can customize class `ShellContent` and add a new `BindableProperty`  to represent which text color it should use .

1. Create a new class name MyShell which inherit from `ShellContent` ,and create a new **BindableProperty** named `TextColor` .

```
   public class MyShell : ShellContent
   {
       public static readonly BindableProperty TextColorProperty =
  BindableProperty.Create("TextColor", typeof(Color), typeof(MyShell), null);


       public Color TextColor
       {
           get { return (Color)GetValue(TextColorProperty); }
           set { SetValue(TextColorProperty, value); }
       }
   }
```

2. Use **MyShell** instead of `ShellContent` in xaml and assign the value on `TextColor` property.

```
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems"  >
        <local:MyShell
            TextColor="Red"           
            FlyoutIcon="dotnet_bot.svg"
            Title="11111"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            Route="MainPage" />
        
        <local:MyShell
            TextColor="Blue"
            FlyoutIcon="dotnet_bot.svg"          
            Title="22222"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            Route="MainPage" />

        <local:MyShell
            TextColor="Green"
            FlyoutIcon="dotnet_bot.svg"           
            Title="22222"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
            Route="MainPage" />
    </FlyoutItem>
```

3. Define `Shell.ItemTemplate` and customize on the Label(TextColor).

```
   <Shell.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="0.2*,0.8*">
                <Image Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}"
                       Margin="5"
                       HeightRequest="45" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Title}"
                       TextColor="{Binding TextColor}"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.ItemTemplate>
```